# Why does Firefox fail to update UpdatePanel after an async file upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, telerik, updatepanel

This process has been working fine in Chrome, but in Firefox 7.0.1 there are problems.

I have an Ajax `AsyncFileUpload` and an Update Panel containing Literal controls for file information and an Image control for preview, the `AsyncFileUpload` is outside the `UpdatePanel`. When the `AsyncFileUpload` fires upload complete the client side event calls a hidden Button in the `UpdatePanel`, which in turn fires a server side event that sets the fields and image in the `UpdatePanel` and tells it to update.

The weird thing is that this process works fine when another hidden button is called before the `AsyncFileUpload` uploads an image. The update panel sets and shows the details for the current image fine, but when the user pick the replacement image the file upload completes and the button click is fired, the code sets the data but the page does not show any changes. There are errors in the web console but I have no idea what they mean and I've googled them to death, I have pasted them below.

```
Error: c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(a, null) is null
Source File: http://localhost:3271/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?
_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_MainContent_ScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1
&_TSM_CombinedScripts_= %3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d3.5.0.0%2c+
Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken (removed long string o stuff) Line: 6463
```

I have switched the telerik Rad Script Manager out for the standard asp Script Manager and now receive this error instead, I don't know if it's related.

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Index or size is negative or greater than 
the allowed amount"  code: "1" nsresult: "0x80530001 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INDEX_SIZE_ERR)"  
location: "http://localhost:3271/ScriptResource.axd? (removed long string o stuff)
Line: 191"]
```

**EDIT** Chrome is throwing this error

```
Uncaught Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
```

**EDIT** I have been through the script includes and cleared out any possible conflicting files, it has not fixed the issue though, there is a new error though in Firefox though

```
Error: c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(a, null) is null
Source File: http://localhost:3271/ScriptResource.axd?d=... Line: 16
```

**EDIT** IE8 throwing this error, none of the site is working in IE8

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
.NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR     
3.5.21022; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Tue, 18 Oct 2011 13:21:11 UTC

Message: Invalid argument. Line: 202 Char: 17 Code: 0
URI: ScriptResource.axd?d=...
```

If you need any further explanation or information then please ask, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely you have a script conflict.  Remove all script references that are not related to the file upload.  Make sure it works then add the others back, one by one, to find the culprit.

Comment: I'm afraid that this did not fix the issue, I went through the script includes and removed/replaced what I could but it does not seem to have done anything, thanks for your help.

Comment: Forgot to mention to please see my edits above, thanks again!